# ¿Como puedo llamar la talblas que han sido creadas en la base de datos por un usuario?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-8, controller

desde ya, gracias por leer mi pregunta, lo que quiero lograr es llamar todas las tablas que el usuario ha creado en la base de datos, les explico el contexto tengo un controlador donde el usuario por medio de un formulario crea sus propias tablas en la base de datos el mismo usuario asigana el nombre de la tabla y sus campos ahora lo que quiero lograr es traer el nombre de todas esas tablas creadas por el usuario, esto sonara un poco extraño pero es lo que tengo que lograr, comparto mi controlador donde creo la tabla.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Admin\Catalogs;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CatAdministratorController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $tableName = $request->input('name');
           
            if (!Schema::hasTable($tableName)) {
                Schema::create($tableName, function($table) use ($request)
                {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    foreach ($request['elements'] as $item) {
                        $table->string($item, $request->number);
                    }
                    $table->timestamps();
                });    
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'El catalago ya ha sido creado',
                ]);
            }
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Catalogo creado exitosamente',
            ], 200);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function insertCatalog()
    {

    }
}
```

En el metodo Store creo las tablas con los campos del formulario ahora en el metodo index necesito llamar esas tablas creadas.

Comment: Bueno para resolver tu problema lo ideal que se podría hacer es crear una tabla de registro, es decir cada vez que un usuario cree tablas, insertas registros del nombre de la tabla y el id del usuario que creó a tabla, ya si quisieras saber que tablas creó el usuario solo consultarías directamente la tabla ej: tbl_users

Comment: en tu metodo store, crearias las tablas y ademas insertarias nuevos registros en la tabla ej: tbl_users

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios me son utiles para generar ideas, ire actaulizando la pregunta hasta dar con el resultado esperado de nuevo muchas gracias.

Comment: Hay métodos para leer todas las tablas que existen en una BD MySql, puedes consultar aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-information.html
Las sentencias necesarias pueden usarse con `DB::select('tu query');`